# Solve overdetermined systems using cgal Quadratic Programming

Tags: c++, cgal, quadratic-programming

I want to solve an overdetermined system of the form `Ax=b` where `A` is a `(m x n)` matrix (with `m>n`), `b` is a `(m)` vector and `x` is the vector of the unknowns. I want also to bound the solution with `lb` and `ub`.

Giving the following program:
(QP)minimize `transpose(x).D.x+transpose(c).x+c0` subject to   `Ax⋛b,l≤x≤u`

I wonder how to calculate the matrix D and the vector c. Because the matrix D has to be symmetric I have defined it as `D=transpose(A).A` and `c` as `c=-transpose(A).b`. My question is: Is this representation correct? If no, how should I define D and c?

Answer (score 0):

"Solving" an overdetermined system `Ax = b` usually means computing a solution `x` which minimizes the euclidean norm of the error `e(x) = ||Ax-b||`. If you have additional linear constraints of the form `l <= x <= u` then indeed you get a Quadratic Program:

```
min { 0.5*e(x)^2 } <=> min { 0.5*(Ax-b)'*(Ax-b) } 
               <=> min { 0.5*x'*A'*A*x -b'Ax + 0.5*b'b) }
               <=> min { 0.5*x'*A'*A*x -b'Ax }
```

subject to the linear constraints

```
l <= x <= u
```

So you can define the matrix `D` to be **half** the `A'*A` (`A'` means `A transposed`):

```
D = 1/2*A'*A
```

and vector `c` to satisfy

```
c' = -b'*A => c = -A'*b
```

So your approach is not correct, but it was close!

Comment: Thanks a lot Giorgos.